# Preventing duplicates with multiple collects in cypher query - which is the more canonical approach?

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I was initially caught off guard by `cypher` returning a cross product of multiple `collect` statements for a query.

To remove duplicates in the returned values; which is the more canonical (or otherwise preferred) approach out of the two examples below:

Option A:

```
MATCH (a)
MATCH (a)-->(b)
WITH a, collect(b) as bs
MATCH (a)-->(c)
RETURN a, bs, collect(c) as cs
```

Option B:

```
MATCH (a)
MATCH
    (a)-->(b),
    (a)-->(c)
RETURN
    a,
    collect(DISTINCT b) as bs,
    collect(DISTINCT c) as cs
```

I'm assuming option A has better performance.

Answer (score 1):

Since both your constructs only return results if the full pattern

```
 (b)<--(a)-->(c)
```

exists,the shortest way would be

```
MATCH (b)<--(a)-->(c)
RETURN
    a,
    collect(DISTINCT b) as bs,
    collect(DISTINCT c) as cs
```

In case one or both of the two edges is/are optional, and you can use apoc, you can also do something like:

```
MATCH (a)
RETURN
    a,
    apoc.coll.toSet([(a)-->(b) | b]) as bs,
    apoc.coll.toSet([(a)-->(c) | b]) as cs
```

Comment: Interesting. Thanks.